# Understanding the GIT work flow on remote server

Tags: git

I have worked for years on projects using Ftp to access files on servers but really want to start using version control. I am brand new to this. I mainly work in html, php, css etc etc

If I understand correctly I bring a copy of the source files down locally, then work on them and then push them back up to the server.

But, here's how I want it to work...

I'd like to leave everything on the server and instead create a directory e.g. public_html/staging/ then copy everything from /public_html/ in there.

Then I can see it live, but not live, if that makes sense. I will work on only the files in /public_html/staging/. Then when I've made changes I simply want to push the changes to the 'live' site under /public_html/

Is that a good flow? Is that how I should do it?

If so, can anyone recommend where I can find examples of how to set this up as almost all tutorials etc refer to bringing files down locally then pushing them back up.

Comment: You aren't required to push the files up; Use git locally (Make sure you backup in case of hdd failures etc), and use your current ftp workflow for pushing things to production.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no changes to remote repository, you don't have to pull them to local. And about staging sub-folder: navigate to that folder using git and there type `git init`. It will create empty git repository. Than copy all files you need to that directory, `git add -A`, `git commit -m "My commit"` and by doing this, you will be tracking only staging sub-directory.